# How could I target these elements in javascript? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have some To Do-s that are dinamically created by the user:

```
<div>
  <h3 class = 'taskTitle'>do homework </h3> 
  <p class = 'taskDate'>Expires: 2021.12.31</p>
   <input type = button class = 'delBtn' value = 'x'></input>
  <input type = button class = 'expandBtn' value = '...'></input>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class = 'taskTitle'>workout </h3> 
  <p class = 'taskDate'>Expires: 2021.10.11</p>
  <input type = button class = 'delBtn' value = 'x'></input>
  <input type = button class = 'expandBtn' value = '...'></input>
</div>
**etc.**
```

On click of the expandBtn a pop up window appears that would contain the title (h3) and the date (p) of the specific To Do.
**script**:

function showDescription(){

```
const expandBtns= document.querySelectorAll('.expandBtn')
expandBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){

        let popUp = document.createElement('div')
        popUp.classList.add('descriptionBox')

        let title = event.target.parentNode.firstChild.textContent **<--says its undefined**
        let date = event.target.parentNode.firstChild.textContent **<--says its undefined**

        popUp.innerHTML = `
            <h3>${title}</h3>
            <p class = 'description'> lorem ipsum  </p>
            <p class = 'dateDescription'>${date}</p>
            <input class = 'delDescription' type = button value = 'x'></input>`
        
        const todos = document.querySelector('#todos')
        todos.appendChild(popUp)

        //close button for popUp
        const delDescription = document.querySelectorAll('.delDescription')
        delDescription.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function (event){
                event.target.parentNode.remove()
            })
        })

        // alert(document.querySelector('.activeProject').textContent)
    })
})
```

}

So how could I target them? querySelector isn't good either, as I have more than 1 To Do-s. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered giving all the `div` elements a common class?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a unique id or class to all the `div` elements. For example:

```
<div id="to-do-1"><p>Test</p></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("to-do-1").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>
<style>
#to-do-1 {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.children` will get you what you want:

```js
document.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  if (ev.target.className!=="expandBtn") return;
  const [name,date]=[...ev.target.parentNode.children].slice(0,2).map(e=>e.textContent)
  console.log(name,date);
  // further code for popup ...
})
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class = 'taskTitle'>do homework </h3> 
  <p class = 'taskDate'>Expires: 2021.12.31</p>
  <input type = button class = 'delBtn' value = 'x'></input>
  <input type = button class = 'expandBtn' value = '...'></input>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class = 'taskTitle'>workout </h3> 
  <p class = 'taskDate'>Expires: 2021.10.11</p>
  <input type = button class = 'delBtn' value = 'x'></input>
  <input type = button class = 'expandBtn' value = '...'></input>
</div>
```

`.firstChild` will return the first `childNode`, which in your case would have been a blank and a line-break and *not* the `<h3>` element you expected.

`.children` on the other hand will return a collection of all child *elements* (like: `<div>, <p>, <span>, ...` etc.), the chained `.slice(0,2)` will slice off the first two elements only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all `expandBtn`

- `var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("expandBtn")`

2. Create a loop and addEventListener for all of them

```
for(let i =0; i < btn.length; i++) { 
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function () { 
    let h3 = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
    let p = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    alert("h3 = "+ h3.innerText + " & p = " + p.innerText);
  }
}
```

- now when the user clicking on anyone of them it's will search for h3, p  who is belong to the parent of this button